# Join query based on name of the Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, join, entity-framework-4

I have a database that gets loaded based on Template T. However, now I want to join other tables based on strings or passing in a "T2" Template.

How can I create a function like this to generate an IQueryable?

```
public void createJoinedTable<T, T2>(T2 join_table, string join_on_this_property, string order, string order_by)
            where T : class
            where T2 : class
   {

            var table = GetGenericTable<T>(); // I have the IQueryable<T> of the main table. 
            // now join the joined table.
            var id = 1;
            table = table    // your starting point - table in the "from" statement
               .Join(join_table, // the source table of the inner join
                  firsttable => post.myid,        // Select the primary key (the first part of the "on" clause in an sql "join" statement)
                  secondtable => meta.othertableid,   // Select the foreign key (the second part of the "on" clause)
                  (firsttable, secondtable) => new { Unknown = firsttable , Unknown2 = secondtable}) // selection
               .Where(x => x.Unknown.ID == id);    // where statement

           table = table.CustomOrderByDescending(order_by, direction); // custom ordering by string
           m_queryable = table; // record results.
   }
```

The problem is, that I cannot do a .Join() because it is not constrained by the Entity class. It's constrained as a generic "class".

Where T : class instead of where T: MyEntityTable

Well, if I did that in the arguments, then what's the point of having a "generic join table function"?

I want to be able to join whatever I want and based on text-based arguments.

How would I use "join_on_this_property" to help me accomplish this?

BONUS Challenge: Join unlimited amounts of tables based on "List tables, List join_ON_properties"--but that could be very complicated.

Comment: Two things - first you're trying to *strongly type* something based on dynamic requirements, and second (related) I think you're finding that your approach isn't *generic* but depends on the types themselves. You might need to rethink this design.

Comment: How would I redesign it? I just want to be able to join tables in a generic way, using just "strings", I don't like dealing with so many types. I want to be able to put this code in a lot of different pages with different database tables. At best I can call them with the entity Class that it should use, and the name of the properties to join the tables together.

Comment: One of the primary benefits of EF is that it's strongly-typed. If you want something dynamic, why not just use dynamic SQL statements?

Comment: Because then I wouldn't be able to autogenerate models, call linq and entity constraints and functions, lazy loading, simply changing classes and then pushing them for updates. The whole point of EF is so that we have a modern way of dealing with SQL without writing SQL queries.

Comment: Instead of `string join_on_this_property` why not just pass an `Func<T>` which can be used directly in the `Where()` method then? I can't even imagine the use-case for this where you'd want to pass in the property as a `string`.

Comment: Well that's a great idea, I just don't use "Exp" (I think you mean Expression<Func<>>?) much so I didn't think of it. How would you code this and how would you even call it? I'm not sure how this is going to work, I don't use reflection much.

Comment: Well, I'm just going to make a "View" instead, because joins are too hard in EntityFramework.